# Need to override a swipe up or swipedown in wkWebView

Tags: swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am writing an app that displays *something* in a viewController. That something can be an image (UIImageView), an mp4 (AVIPlayerViewController), a URL (wkWebView), or a PDF (wkWebView).

I create a new viewcontroller based on the type of item, and do addsubview to my parent controller.

In addition, I created a tap gesture recognizer, a swipe up and a swipe down.

Tap works for all types of controller.

SwipeUp or SwipeDown works for everything EXCEPT the wkWebView controller, so I know I have wired everything up correctly.

I am almost positive this behaviour is because the wkwebview uses the swipes as a scroll mechanism.

My question, therefore, is: How can I override the swipe up and down so my code gets it first, then passes it on to the wkwebview controller? I need this to control a timer I have running in the background that detects 30 seconds of idle time. The swipe needs to reset the timer, and my selector event is not firing (but, as i said, ONLY when in the wkWebView!).

Thank you,
Jerry

Comment: Please add a [example] to your question showing what you have already tried.